# Django make query about .save()

Tags: python, django

DB TABLE (null is ok)

```
select * from TESTDB;
id | AAA | BBB | CCC |
======================
```

Django code

```
new_dataset = TESTDB(BBB = 222)
new_dataset.save()
```

I want to change code like this...

```
target_field = 'BBB'
new_dataset = TESTDB( target_field = 222 )
new_dataset.save()
```

How can I complete this code?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dict as keyword arguments feature](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) of Python:

```
target_field = 'BBB'
new_dataset = TESTDB(**{target_field: 222})
new_dataset.save()
```

Comment: This is the right way to do it, but it would be better written as `testdb_kwargs = { 
    'BBB': 222,
}
new_dataset = TESTDB.objects.create(**testdb_kwargs)`